# Nifi vs Talend?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, talend

I have been trying to understand Nifi and Talend for sometime now and there are some questions that are bothering me.

1. Where does Nifi excel in data flow management apart from being a light weight than talend?
2. How good is talend when it comes to realtime data processing from different sources such as MySQL, Casandra etc.
3. How time consuming is it to do ETL in talend pitched against Nifi with Spark in processing data?
4. What are the other areas that one might be better than other (Incase someone has a better point to pitch)?

It would be really helpful if someone has also some data points to say anything about this?

Comment: skim through few of  the top links, you will certainly get some sense about overall differences - https://www.google.com/search?q=nifi+vs+talend&oq=nifi+vs+ta&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60.7551j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There isn't a single link in that I have not visited and it wasn't giving the right answers and that's the reason beind the question. But I really appreciate your response.If you have any experience with this please share your prespective.

Comment: We use NiFi extensively, so if you are looking to implement any specific use case then feel free to post but don't have much idea about Talend, thanks!